# Vue tree navigation (pluggin) how to map routes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

[image]

I have used [vue-tree-navigation](https://github.com/MisRob/vue-tree-navigation) for implement this **Tree navigation menu** .
When I hit a menu item (eg :- Create item) it should route to the create item component.
But it's only print the name of the route in the navigation bar and doesn't route to any where.

```
http://localhost:8080/inside#item
```

how do I fixed this problem?

this is my **routes.js file**

```
const routes = [

  { path: "/", component: welcome },
  {
    path: "/inside",
    component: inside,
    name: inside,
    children: [
      { path: "/category", component: category, name: category },
      { path: "/sub-category", component: subCategory, name: subCategory },
      { path: "/item", component: item, name: item }
    ]
  }
];
```

**This is my component**

```
<template>
    <div class="inside">
        <div class="sideBar"><vue-tree-navigation :items="items" /></div>
        <div class="content"><router-view></router-view></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [ 
              { name: 'Item Master', route: 'inside', children: [          // /about
                { name: 'Create item category', element: 'category', },
                { name: 'Create item sub category', element: 'sub-category', },
                { name: 'Create item', element: 'item', },

              ]},
            ],
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: your sub menu item has no route property,where are you going when menu clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change a bit of things in the router file, it works well for me:

- The components starts in Uppercase (just a convention)
- The name with ''
- Delete the / in the path

Like this:

```
path: "inside",
component: Inside,
name: "inside",
children: [
  { path: "category", component: Category, name: 'category' },
  { path: "sub-category", component: SubCategory, name: 'subCategory' },
  { path: "item", component: Item, name: 'item' }
]
```

And the most important, load (*if you are not doing it already*) the *VueRouter* with:

```
var router = new VueRouter({
const routes = [
...
]
});
```

Hope it helps!